# Convert Array to Object by key of array

Tags: javascript, lodash

What is the best way to convert:

Dynamically I am getting an array.

For example we can consider this following array.

```
[
    'typeRead_1',
    'typeModify_1',
    'typeModify_2',
    'typeRead_3',
];
```

But I want it something like this.
to:

```
{
    1: {
      typeRead: true,
      typeModify: true,
    },
    2: {
      typeRead: false,
      typeModify: true,
    },
    3: {
      typeRead: true,
      typeModify: false,
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing this:

```js
const items = [
    'typeRead_1',
    'typeModify_1',
    'typeModify_2',
    'typeRead_3',
];

const ret = items.reduce((ret, el) => {
      let [prop, key] = el.split('_');
      if (!ret[key]) ret[key] = { typeRead: false, typeModify: false };
      ret[key][prop] = true;
      return ret;
    }, {})
    
console.log(ret)
```